# CosmosDB: How does SELECT TOP work?

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a 450GB database... with millions of records.

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM c WHERE c.type='water';
```

To speed up our queries, I thought about just taking the first one but we have noticed that the query still takes quite a while, despite the very first record in the database matching our constraints.

So, my question is, how does the `SELECT TOP 1` really work? Does it:

**A)** Select ALL records and then return just the first (top) one where
    `type='water'`

**B)** Return the first record which is encountered where `type='water'`

Comment: What's the schema of `c`? Is the field `type` indexed?

Comment: Maybe it takes a long time to find a match.

Comment: @Jacobm001type is not indexed yet, but will be at a later date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have tested when the very first (or at least in the top 10) record matches. I'm really just interested in how the select TOP works.

Comment: @pookie Just out of curiosity, did you specifically opt out of indexing the `type` property? By default all fields in Cosmos are indexed and you have to go out of your way to turn off this behavior for specific JSON paths.

Comment: @JesseCarter Nope, I did not touch the indexing policies.

Comment: @pookie If you haven't adjusted the indexing policies then type is definitely indexed and the accepted answer is not correct

Comment: @JesseCarter Thanks, but if the answer I marked is not correct and you know the correct answer, could you please post your answer?

Comment: While running the top query getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Did Top  work for you ?

Comment: @ArpanSaini Yes, Top did work for me, hence the question.

Comment: @pookie : it seems Cosmos db Explorer issue, Top worked for me in SDK call, between thanks for the response

Answer (score 27):

Try this line, noting the offset limit:

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.type='water' OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1`

For more information about the offset limit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-offset-limit

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you aren't sorting your results (which you query isn't) then `TOP 1` will return the first result as soon as it finds one. This should then end the query.

Comment: Great, thanks, it makes sense that it takes the first record and then stops searching, but I was not convinced it was doing that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apparently, CosmosDB indexes everything by default. Since I've not touched any indexing policies, c.type _is_ indexed and therefore your second paragraph is not correct. I've unmarked it as the solution so if you can, please update your answer so that it can be considered again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos db Explorer doesn't work with the TOP Command, It's an existing issue. It works fine in SDK Call.

Check some Top command usage below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery

Comment: Now there is a "New SQL Query" button to open an editor, which can run a complete query.